# The requested module '/src/context/TransactionContext.jsx' does not provide an export named 'TransactionsProvider'

Tags: reactjs

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/context/TransactionContext.jsx' does not provide an export named 'TransactionsProvider'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAsbQ.png)

Help me with this. trying to get rid of this. Is there any careless mistake

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import 'TransactionProvider' from TransactionContext.jsx but there is no export with this name.

There are two potential solutions but not sure which you need without seeing the code so you can try one of these:

1. In TransactionContext.tsx make sure the overall function is exported for example:

```
export const TransactionProvider = () => {
  return <div>example</div>
}
```

The key here is the export identifier before the function declaration, once you do this, you can import TransactionProvider.

2. You might be exporting the wrong function, if your file is called TransactionContext then your exported function inside will likely have the same name. If this is the case then instead of importing TransactionProvider you should import TransactionContext

That's as much insight as I can provide *without seeing the code for TransactionContext.jsx*

---

Just in case it helps, here is a basic example as well. **Try to compare what you did differently with exports, imports, and function names:**

### Make sure the component is exported:

```
    //this is file ExampleComponent.jsx
    export const ExampleComponent = () => {
      return <div>ExampleComponent</div>;
    };
    
    export default ExampleComponent;
```

### Import and use it in another component

```
    import ExampleComponent from "./ExampleComponent";  
    //example usage - see how I use the same name as the export in ExampleComponent.jsx. 
    export const app = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <ExampleComponent />
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default app;
```

Notice how if we declare a function or component, we must use the same name to import it